# Can I use Google app Engine Blobstore without servlet request/response?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have a layer above the servlet layer. It lets me use output/input streams quite easily without the HTTP hassle.

In that layer, I don't have a reference to HttpServlet Request/Response. GAE blobstore requires a reference to the response/request classes.

Can I somehow work with GAE blobstore without providing the http servlet response/request classes? I couldn't find a way :(

API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService

Comment: I don't know anything about Java on appengine, but why would the datastore require request/response I would have thought thats only required to interact with the web client.  Certainly the python datastore api doesn't require it in any way, or are you confusing terms here and you don't really mean the datastore.

Comment: I meant blobstore. Fixed the question, tags and also added link to the API. It's the middle of the night here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a paid app that uses the [Socket Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/).

Comment: It's a technical question regarding using GAE Blobstore outside servlet request/response. I think it's related to Socket Java API indirectly. The paid part I don't get either. Thanks for trying. Appreciate it or I wouldn't have spent time writing this comment. Cheers.